# OAS with Includes

Tags: specifications, oas

New to OAS.  Can someone recommend how you would create an OAS Specification with reusable files (or snippets) that can be included in multiple specifications?  Every example I can see references to components in the same specification, but I want it to be a separate file so it can be referenced by multiple specifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference can be any relative URI. Most examples you find show references to the same file using the fragment of the URI, that is everything after the `#` (hash), but you can also put stuff before it, including a path to a different file.

E.g.:

```yaml
# Pet.yml
Pet:
  type: object
  properties:
    name:
      type: string
      example: "doge"
```

```yaml
# API.yml
...
      responses:
        "200":
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "./Pet.yml#/Pet"
```

This way you can split your spec into multiple files (and folders) and reuse those in multiple API specs as well.

**Note:** this assumes version 3 of OAS, not sure if it works with previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

use https://redocly.com/docs/cli | `npm i @redocly/cli`

it's powerful toolbox with much more than just extended `$ref`s

they support relative paths in filesystem and even [remote URL](https://redocly.com/docs/resources/ref-guide/#definition-is-a-file-at-a-remote-url) in [references ($refs)](https://redocly.com/docs/resources/ref-guide/#definition-is-a-file-at-a-remote-url)

when your definition with non-standard references is done just [bundle](https://redocly.com/docs/cli/commands/bundle) it out

PS check out all other very useful [commands](https://redocly.com/docs/cli/commands)